# Parsing data from a string

Tags: r, excel, text-parsing, string-parsing

I think this is something that experienced programmers do all the time. But, given my limited programming experience, please bear with me.

I have an excel file which has particular cell entries that read

> [[{"from": "4", "response": true, "value": 20}, {"from": "8", "response": true, "value": 20}, {"from": "9", "response": true, "value": 20}, {"from": "3", "response": true, "value": 20}], [{"from": "14", "response": false, "value": 20}, {"from": "15", "response": true, "value": 20}, {"from": "17", "response": false, "value": 20}, {"from": "13", "response": true, "value": 20}]]

Now, for each such entry I want to take the information in each of the curly brackets and make a row of data out of it. Each such row would have 3 columns. For example, the row formed from the first entry within curly brackets should have the entries "4" "true" and "20" respectively. The part I posted should give me 6 such rows, and for n such repetitions I should end up with a matrix of 6n rows, and 4 columns ( an identifier, plus the 3 columns mentioned).

What would be most efficient way to do this? By "doing this" I mean learning the trick, and then implementing it. I have access to quite a few software packages(Excel, Stata, Matlab, R) in my laboratory, so that should not be an issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! please include in your question examples of things you have already tried and research you have done to try and solve your problem, this will help us formulate a good answer for you :)

Comment: Where does the Identifier for the fourth column come from?  I don't see it in your data.  Since the file is already in Excel, and since the cell contents seem well formed, I would just use Regular Expressions to parse out the data; a User Defined Object and collection to gather it together, and then place the output on a new sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a `JSON` style file.  What you've got is actually a list of two data objects.  We can turn them into R data frames with the `jsonlite` package.  Try this:

```
txt <- '[[{"from": "4", "response": true, "value": 20}, {"from": "8", "response": true, "value": 20}, {"from": "9", "response": true, "value": 20}, {"from": "3", "response": true, "value": 20}], [{"from": "14", "response": false, "value": 20}, {"from": "15", "response": true, "value": 20}, {"from": "17", "response": false, "value": 20}, {"from": "13", "response": true, "value": 20}]]'

library(jsonlite)
rbind.pages(fromJSON(txt))   ## just fromJSON(txt) for the list
#   from response value
# 1    4     TRUE    20
# 2    8     TRUE    20
# 3    9     TRUE    20
# 4    3     TRUE    20
# 5   14    FALSE    20
# 6   15     TRUE    20
# 7   17    FALSE    20
# 8   13     TRUE    20
```

If this is in a file, and the file is called e.g. `"new.txt"`, then you can use

```
rbind.pages(fromJSON(readLines("new.txt")))
```

Comment: I could not find a package rjsonlite on CRAN, they do have something called rjson though.

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing that. Typing in: 
install.packages("jsonlite")
Output:
Warning in install.packages("jsonlite") :
  argument 'lib' is missing: using 'C:\Users\Econ Grad\Documents/R/win-library/2.8'
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/2.8
Warning message:
package ‘jsonlite’ is not available

Comment: pak's idea was right. When I re-installed the most recent R package on my personal laptop, I could install jsonlite and the code worked fine. Thanks for your response, I will work on the code, and might ask you again, if I get stuck somewhere again.

Comment: The function rbind.pages takes a string as input. Now, if I have a list of strings, could you kindly tell me how to extend it to the list, so that my final data contains parsed output from all the strings in the list?

Comment: `rbind.pages` takes a list as input.  I'm not sure what you're asking.  Maybe it might be good to ask a new question about that.

Comment: Changing my answer to a comment since it's more appropriate.... Richard's answer is good. Juanito, the reason you're getting the warning about accessing the repository is that you're using a very old version of R, and there isn't a package repository for 2.8 on the mirror you're telling it to look at (it starts at 2.12). If you want to use jsonlite, you might need to try a different mirror. Failing that- and it's possible that jsonlite hasn't been or can't be built for 2.8 - you should upgrade your R installation. Which you should probably do anyway.